# load data to select from XML file by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to load the select control (drop down list) with data from an xml file.
This is the code to load the xml file:

```
 x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("User");
```

"User" is the tag i want to catch if i found it, then update into sub-tags like:
"UserName","Password","Type".
After catch "User" update depending on select.selected.
Update "Password" will be from Textbox.
Update "Type" will be from select.
This is the code i write but it doesn't get my output, any one could help by new code or edit my code.

```
var select = document.getElementById("updater");
for (i = 0; i &lt; x.length; i++) {
     select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("UserName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,  
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("UserName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}

select.onchange = function update() {
     for (i = 0; i &lt; x.length; i++) {
          if (document.getElementById("updater").value = x[i].getElementsByTagName("UserName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)) {
             document.getElementById("password").value = document.getElementsByTagName("Password")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
             document.getElementById("Type").value = document.getElementsByTagName("Type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          }
     }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq

```
content_login = Enumerable.From(data)
                .Where(function (x) {
                    var Name = x.getElementsByTagName("UserName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                    return Name == userName && Pass == Password; //If condition true it will execute Select
                })
                .Select(function (x) {

                    return Fields;
                }).ToString();
```